# Optimal solution of regularized empirical risk minimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm trying to show for general regularized empirical risk minimization problem that the minimizing $w$ for

$$\min_{w} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{n}^{i-1}\phi_{i}\left ( w^{T}X_{i} \right ) + \lambda g(w)$$

for some $\lambda>0$, where $\phi_{i}'s$ and $g$ are convex functions. And $\alpha^{*}$ be  an optimal solution of its dual problem

$$\max_{\alpha} -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{n}^{i-1}\phi_{i}^{*}\left (-\alpha_{i} \right ) - \lambda g^{*}\left ( \frac{1}{\lambda n} X\alpha \right )$$

where $\phi_{i}^{*}$ and $g^{*}$ are the conjugate of $\phi_{i}$ and $g$ respectively. How is the optimal value $w^{*}$ = $\nabla g^{*} \left ( \frac{1}{n\lambda}X\alpha^{*} \right )$ assuming that $g^{*}$ is differentiable at $\left ( \frac{1}{n\lambda}X\alpha^{*} \right )$?

Comment: The version of regularised empirical risk minimisation mentioned here is unconstrained. How do you convert it to a dual problem? What kind of conjugates are $\phi_i^*$ and $g^*$?

Comment: @Shiv Tavker the dual problem was formulated by making it a constrained optimization problem via $y_{i}=w^{T}x_{i}$  and $\phi_{i}^{*}$ , $g^{*}$ this also might be helpful: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/frostig15-supp.pdf